# Binance, ccxt futures, problem about amount in order

Tags: binance, binance-api-client, ccxt

I got an interest about ccxt these days, especially futures trade

i tried to make a logic and it was fun

but I've got a problem to "Setting amount"

```
def binance_long():
    order = binance.create_market_buy_order(
        symbol = symbol,
        amount=0.001
    )

def binance_short():
    order = binance.create_market_sell_order(
        symbol=symbol,
        amount=0.001
    )
```

this is my buy/sell function

In that codes, I want to put my whole usdt dollars

but i don't know how to change amount

because that 0.001 position is based on btc not usdt

how can i put my whole usdt dollars in my position?

ex)729.8 usdt -> put that whole thing

also using leverage too (1~50)

and also how can i close my position with my whole usdt?

because In order, I understood that I had to write this function and then use this function.

1. binance_long() <- buy long position
2. binance_short() <- close long position

like this

schedule.every().monday.at("00:00:00").do(binance_long)

schedule.every().monday.at("00:00:30").do(binance_short)

To Open position and Close position in Long position

Comment: I solved amount problem but i don't know where am i have to multiply the leverage in this logic. this is my amount function.

`def cal_amount(usdt_balance, cur_price): #usde based
    portion = 1 #100%  in my wallet
    usdt_trade = usdt_balance * portion
    amount = math.floor((usdt_trade * 1000000)/cur_price) / 1000000
    return amount `

Comment: Also what if market price changes meanwhile?